# localhost yes but phpmyadmin blank

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp

WAMP
people having problem with both localhost and phpmyadmin loads blank which usually the port problem.
Mine is only phpmyadmin blank.
sqlbuddy and phpinfo no problem.

tried uninstall reinstalled wamp. tried xampp, same problem, all works well, not phpmyadmin.

mysql log:

```
120905  8:03:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
120905  8:03:08 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120905  8:03:08 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
120905  8:03:08 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120905  8:03:09 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120905  8:03:09 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120905  8:03:09 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
120905  8:03:09  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
120905  8:03:10 InnoDB: 1.1.8 started; log sequence number 1595675
120905  8:03:11 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '(null)'; port: 3306
120905  8:03:11 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '::';
120905  8:03:11 [Note]   - '(null)' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
120905  8:03:11 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
120905  8:03:13 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
120905  8:03:13 [Note] wampmysqld: ready for connections.
```

apache log

```
[Wed Sep 05 08:03:09 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.22 (Win32) PHP/5.4.3 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Sep 05 08:03:09 2012] [notice] Server built: May 13 2012 13:32:42
[Wed Sep 05 08:03:09 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3812
[Wed Sep 05 08:03:09 2012] [notice] Child 3812: Child process is running
[Wed Sep 05 08:03:09 2012] [notice] Child 3812: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Sep 05 08:03:09 2012] [notice] Child 3812: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Sep 05 08:03:09 2012] [notice] Child 3812: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Sep 05 08:03:09 2012] [notice] Child 3812: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Sep 05 08:04:14 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Wed Sep 05 08:09:50 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/favicon.ico
[Wed Sep 05 08:41:03 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/phpMyAdmin
```

Comment: what WAMP do you mean ? wampserver.com ? WAMP is just the short form for Windows-Apache-MySQL-PHP and there are a lot of WAMP-stacks out there...

Comment: wampServer. but that is not the problem. wampserver, xampp, easyphp all tried, all works except phpmyadmin

Answer (score 2):

```
[Wed Sep 05 08:41:03 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/phpMyAdmin
```

I guess this shows why your phpmyadmin is blank?

Comment: The file is there. In the package of WampServer. I din change anything.

Comment: but according to the log, why is the file missing? Try verifying it, if it is there, try check the file name it might have caused by the case sensitivity.

Comment: uninstalled, reinstalled. no more the line File does not exist: C:/wamp/www/phpMyAdmin.  Still it is blank.

Comment: Try uninstall WAMP then install XAMPP, if it is still blank, download this and put on xampp folder. You can also try putting it into your wamp, but I afraid the settings might be different. Please bear in mind that wamp and xampp phpmyadmin path are different, xampp path will be c:/xampp/phpMyAdmin while wamp will be C:/wamp/www/phpMyAdmin
[link]www.gonegamers.net/phpMyAdmin.rar[/link]

Comment: Can you open any other folder in the same level as phpMyAdmin? If none, create a sample folder and try to access that folder. Also, try creating a sample file in the same folder level as phpMyAdmin folder and try accessing that file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use SQL Yog, it's more powerful than PHPmyadmin.
URL : http://www.webyog.com/en/

Answer (score 1):

Well, after trying to figure this out for 2 days, I finally got some answers as to why I kept getting a blank page after installing xampp and trying to visit the phpMyAdmin.

BE SURE TO LOG INTO YOUR SERVER AS ADMIN!!! I work for a company with a IT team which gave my account admin access and permissions and it still wasn't working. it only seems to work if we log into the server as admin.

or

Install Chrome or firefox on the server. if you use the internet explorer default browser you get a blank page.

windows server 2012

Answer (score 0):

The PHPMyAdmin page is blank or **an error page (404, 403, ...)**?

The PHPMyAdmin folder is not inside the www folder of WampServer because WampServer use **alias** to point to the PHPMyAdmin folder in `C:\wamp\apps\`. You can check my guide [in this article](http://www.webtrunghieu.info/site/web/solve-the-denied-access-problem-when-using-wamp-server-2-on-windows-8-). Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

Install Apache service first and then start it and then go to phpMyAdmin page if you already tried the port solution and it didn't work!